# Initialize multiple values in a struct using one function

Tags: go, struct

I would like to initialize multiple variables in a struct using the same function like so:

```
type temp struct {
    i int
    k int
}

func newtemp(age int) *temp{
    return &temp{
        i, k := initializer(age)
    }
}
func initializer(age int)(int, int){
    return age * 2, age * 3   
}
```

however, I can not due to having to use `:` to initialize variables when creating a struct, is there any way I can do something that is valid yet like the code above?

Comment: What about returning the struct directly from the function?

Comment: you can have the initizalizer func take references: func initializer(i1 *int, i2 *int) { *i1=1; *i2=2} and pass   t:= &temp{}; initializer(&t.i, &t.k) into it

Comment: but it looks like a hack to me, can you maybe give more detail on why you would want to have this initializer function separate from the newTemp ?

Comment: "I would like to <do something the language spec does not allow>." does not make a very good question.

Answer (score 8):

Using [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals) you can't.

Using tuple [assignment](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignments) you can:

```
func newtemp(age int) *temp{
    t := temp{}
    t.i, t.k = initializer(age)
    return &t
}
```

Testing it:

```
p := newtemp(2)
fmt.Println(p)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/K7osShFil3)):

```
&{4 6}
```